Problem with remote connection through RDP or VNC
I would like to re-open this subject, thinking there may have been some progress in the last 4 years.
I want a user to be able to open a session on a desktop computer, sometimes locally in the office and sometimes remotely at home, with the same identification. The remote connection is normally done through RDP or VNC. Both client and server are running Ubuntu.
The user has limited ubuntu skills.
VNC is not an option from a security point of view: anyone sitting at the server display will see what is going on (without the user being aware of it) and will be able to take control of the session on the server.
I can see that RDP has severe limitations: RDP will only work if no user session is already open on the computer. Otherwise, RDP will severely crash, often needing the computer to be rebooted manually.
So RDP is very risky if the user has forgotten to close the session before leaving the office.
I have tried with freerdp-shadow-cli on the server, but all I get are endless error messages.
Is there a solution today to this problem ?
